# Model empty when submitting Form from Partial View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I'm having an issue trying to pass a model from partial view to controller for further processing.

This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IList<ActionRoleEntity> permissionCollection = new SecurityManager().GetPermissionCollection();

    var model = new PermissionsModel
    {
        PermissionCollection = permissionCollection
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

This one in my Index view. which as you would see includes a partial view _Permissions.

```
@model WebApp.ViewModels.PermissionsModel
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#AdminTabs').tabs();
    });
</script>
<div id="AdminTabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Permissions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Insights</a></li>        
    </ul>    
    <div id="tabs-1">        
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("_Permissions"); }
    </div>  
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>            
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my partial view:

```
@model WebApp.ViewModels.PermissionsModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Permissions", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table id="example" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Workflow</th>
            <th>Stage</th>
            <th>Action</th>            
            <th>Read</th>
            <th>Update</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>    
    <tbody>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.PermissionCollection.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.PermissionCollection[i].RoleName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.PermissionCollection[i].Workflow)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.PermissionCollection[i].StageName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.PermissionCollection[i].ActionName)</td>                
                <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.PermissionCollection[i].Get)</td>
                <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.PermissionCollection[i].Post)</td>
                <td>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PermissionCollection[i].hasChanged)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Save" />    
}
```

The model is properly populated for the controller and the html code in the partial view is rendered without any problems. However when I submit the the form by clicking the submit button in _permissions Partial View ... the method "Permissions" in the controller "Admin" that handles that action receives an empty "PermissionModel" model.

This is the code for that action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Permissions(PermissionsModel permissionsModel)
{
    IList<ActionRoleEntity> actionRoleEntity = permissionsModel.PermissionCollection.Where(m => m.hasChanged == true).ToList<vw_ActionRoleEntity>();

    // Save changed permission to database

    return View("Index");
}
```

And finally this is how the Model for Permissions has been coded:

```
public class PermissionsModel
{        
    public IList<ActionRoleEntity> PermissionCollection { get; set; }
}
```

Javascript to update the hasChanged property of an ActionRoelEntity.

```
$("#example input[type='checkbox'").change(function () {
        var arrayCheckboxId = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
        var index = arrayCheckboxId[2]; // Gets specific row Id.
        $('#PermissionCollection_' + index + '__hasChanged').val(true);
    });
```

If you see something I may be missing please advice.

Comment: have you put ``@model WebApp.ViewModels.PermissionsModel`` statement on top of your partial view? it looks like you partial view is not strongly type to the model

Comment: Show the code for the `Permissions` model. Does `PermissionCollection` and its properties have setters?

Comment: @EhsanSaijad - Both Main view and partial view are strongly typed - I missed the line, but have included now. Thanks.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have included the code for PermissionsModel as requested. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this is the real code `@for(..` would throw a parser error - it would need to be just `for(...`. If the properties of `ActionRoleEntity` have setters, then it should be binding to the collection (`Get`, Post` and `hasChanged` should be populated).

Comment: Hi @StephenMuecke. Sure is real code. If changing '@for' to just for ... razor wouldnt know I want to loop in PermissionCollection, neither recognize de var i definition. ActionRoleEntity has getters and setters for properties like this:
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

Comment: it is coming with Count of 0 or it is coming null @jmberon  ??

Comment: Your right - didn't spot your loop is inside a `<table>` element. Can't see any reason why it would not bind those 3 properties. But your `.Where()` clause seems odd. Why would you render elements for `ActionRoleEntity` where the value of `hasChanged` is false if your then going to ignore any changes the user has made to the checkbox states? Make me think you got some javascript involved?

Comment: Yes @StephenMuecke Javascript is involved. This is an Admin form to assign/deny permissions. When a checkbox (Read, Update) in any row is changed then with Javascript I flag the hasChanged property to true. In the controller I am filtering just those rows affected for user changes so I just update in database the necessary permissions. However the PermissionModel has PermissionCollection = null when I receive it in the Permissions method of my controller. I am expecting the same model I set in the get method of the controller plus any variation on checkboxes in the form.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad The property PermissionCollection of the PermissionModel is coming null.

Comment: Is the javascript doing anything except just changing the hidden input value (from `true` to `false` or vice versa)? You not disabling any controls for example?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have included Javascript definition. Basically just change the hasChanged property to true if any change has been applied to any checkbox.

Comment: There are a few problems with your script and it wont change anything, although I don't think it explains why the `PermissionCollection` is `null`.

Comment: BTW, It should be something like `$('#example input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () { $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="hidden"]').val("True"); })` You don't have any inputs with `id="APS_PermissionCollection..."` (or if you do then nothing will bind because your model does not contain a property named `APS`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for the tip mate. Much appreciate it.

Comment: Step 1) In Chrome press F12 just before the post.  Click on the network tab and then press the button to submit the post.  Step 2) Look for the Form data passed back to the controller.  Compare the name value pairs with what you know to be the layout of the permission model.  MVC will always create a null instance of the model on controller entry (right after validation).  Then it tries to match Form data names with model class property names.  If you aren't seeing the data chances are high it's the post not returning proper name value pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look on how your model is name in the Post method and in the view. I see that you called model on the view @**model** WebApp.ViewModels.PermissionsModel and in your lambda assignments the model is **m**, and on your post method is **permissionsModel**. change it to **model** in both places.

Comment: Thank you very much mate. That solved the issue, I was running out of hair because of pulling them out. I have replaced    <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.PermissionCollection[i].RoleName)</td> for    <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.PermissionCollection[i].RoleName)</td> and the method in the controller    
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Permissions(PermissionsModel model){}